# How to make tableview update when new data is added from a different controller

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml

I have two controllers, one controller has a tableview that lists all `members` and the other controller allows a `member` to be added. I am having trouble getting the table to update when a `member` is added. I use two models that are already given to me, so I don't change anything in the models.

Each `member` has an `id` and a `profession`, I use `cellValueFactory` for listing the `members`. I tried adding `listeners` to the `cellValueFactoryProperties` like this:

```
idColumn.cellValueFactoryProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> memberTv.refresh());
```

But it still doesn't show new `members`

The Controller with the TableView:

```
@FXML
TableColumn<Member, Integer> idColumn;
@FXML
TableColumn<Member, String> profColumn;
@FXML
TableView<Member> memberTv;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    memberTv.setItems(getClub().getMembers());
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new 
    ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(cellData.getValue().getId()));
    profColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new 
    ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getProf()));
}
public final Club getClub() {
    \\\returns Club model
}
```

The Controller that adds `members`

```
private int getId() {
    return Integer.parseInt(idTf.getText());
}

private void setId(String id) {
    idTf.setText(id);
}

private String getProf() {
    return profTf.getText();
}

private void setProf(String prof) {
    profTf.setText("" + prof);
}

@FXML
public void handleAddMember(){
    getClub().addMember(getId(), getProf());
}
```

When I add a member I want the TableView to show the added member, but it only shows members already added in the model.

Comment: *"I use two models"* that is a problem, if the models are independent. Usually you work with a single model so that changes can update all views. If this restriction is imposed upon you, the only way of dealing with this is observing the model receiving the *add*-changes and updating the other model accordingly (assuming this is the only model that is modified - otherwise you need to observe both and do updates in both directions).

Comment: @fabian The club model has an ```ObservableList``` for members, there's also a method in the club model that takes ```memberId``` and ```profession``` as parameters to pass into the member model. The club model is the main model and both controllers are connected to the club model. Wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: The existance of methods for passing data does not mean data is actually passed between your models. Also it's impossible to tell, if the communication is properly established in your code. There are quite a lot of questions coming in that get this wrong so I wouldn't be surprised, if you got something wrong in that regard. It's impossible to tell without more info though. You did not post any details about the models or any code that would establish a communication between the models/controllers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had a ClubController that sets the stage based after a menu button is clicked. The problem was that whenever I set a stage I used a new instance of teh Club model instead of using getKiosk(). I changed all the new Club()```` to getClub()``` and it everything works perfectly now.